# How to disable primary color for FormLabel when radio button group is focused?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, jss

When form control is focused then FormLabel is highlighted.How to disable primary color for FormLabel when radio button group is focused and use black instead?

[image]

```
const styles = {
  formLabel: {
    color: "#000"
  },
  formLabelFocused: {
    color: "#000"
  }
};

function App({ classes }) {
  return (
    <FormControl>
      <FormLabel
        classes={{ root: classes.formLabel, focused: classes.formLabelFocused }}
      >
        Options
      </FormLabel>
      <RadioGroup>
        {options.map(option => {
          const { value, label } = option;
          return (
            <FormControlLabel
              control={<Radio />}
              key={value}
              value={value}
              label={label}
            />
          );
        })}
      </RadioGroup>
    </FormControl>
  );
}
```

example https://codesandbox.io/s/st-of-radio-31o2x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When an attempt to override Material-UI's default styles doesn't work, the next step is to look at how the default styles are defined.

Below is an excerpt from [FormLabel.js](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.8.3/packages/material-ui/src/FormLabel/FormLabel.js#L17) showing how the focused styling is defined:

```
export const styles = theme => ({
  /* Styles applied to the root element. */
  root: {
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
    '&$focused': {
      color: theme.palette.primary.main,
    },
  },
  /* Pseudo-class applied to the root element if `focused={true}`. */
  focused: {},
});
```

The effect of this is for the focused color to be specified in a CSS rule like:

```
.MuiFormLabel-root.Mui-focused {
  color: #3f51b5;
}
```

The effect of your override attempt would be more like:

```
.Mui-focused {
  color: #000;
}
```

The default styling uses `.Mui-focused` along with `.MuiFormLabel-root` in order to ensure that the focused styling has higher [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than the non-focused styling. Your override, however, has lower specificity than the default focused styling.

Here is a modified version of your sandbox that works:

```
import React from "react";
import {
  FormControl,
  FormLabel,
  RadioGroup,
  Radio,
  FormControlLabel,
  withStyles
} from "@material-ui/core";

const options = [...Array(4).keys()].map(item => {
  return { value: `value ${item}`, label: `label ${item}` };
});

const styles = {
  formLabel: {
    color: "#000",
    "&.Mui-focused": {
      color: "#000"
    }
  }
};

function App({ classes }) {
  return (
    <FormControl>
      <FormLabel classes={{ root: classes.formLabel }}>Options</FormLabel>
      <RadioGroup>
        {options.map(option => {
          const { value, label } = option;
          return (
            <FormControlLabel
              control={<Radio />}
              key={value}
              value={value}
              label={label}
            />
          );
        })}
      </RadioGroup>
    </FormControl>
  );
}

export default withStyles(styles)(App);
```

[image: Edit Focused FormLabel]

Related references:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity
- https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.8.3/packages/material-ui/src/FormLabel/FormLabel.js#L17
- https://cssinjs.org/jss-plugin-nested/?v=v10.0.3#use--to-reference-selector-of-the-parent-rule

Answer (score -1):

you can add !important.

`const styles = {
  formLabel: {
    color: "#000 !important"
  },
  formLabelFocused: {
    color: "#000"
  }
};`

Comment: It is never necessary to use `!important` when overriding Material-UI styles.